# Unable to create the cache directory (/cache/)

Tags: symfony-2, cache, permissões

Depois que instalei o Fedora, ao tentar entrar na minha aplicação com Symfony2, não consigo arrumar esse erro:

> RuntimeException in bootstrap.php.cache line 2671: Unable to create the cache directory (/cache/)

Já tentei várias alternativas, inclusive as que estão no site oficial, mas nada.

Instalei o PHP pelo terminal, sem Apache pois uso o servidor build-in do PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa excluir o conteúdo da sua pasta `cache` (e também da pasta `logs`, se necessário) e então reconfigurar as permissões da pasta.

Para sistemas que suportam `chmod +a`:

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo chmod +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
$ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

Para sistemas que não suportam `chmod +a`:

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[
w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara tem várias coisas que podem gerar este erro. Aqui estão algumas possíveis soluções.

1- Pode ser a permissão da pasta cache e log que ficam dentro da pasta app do symfony

2- Você pode tentar atualizar os arquivos pelo composer (php composer.phar install ou update), tudo depende de como foi montado o seu projeto.

O mais provável é você utilizar o composer para atualizar, este erro já ocorreu comigo e consegui resolver.